# Is there supposed to be a border between UIToolbar and the status bar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uitoolbar

UI question here; I thought that UIToolbars were supposed to blend in with the status bar? Or is that just for NavigationControllers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIToolBar has a default 1px line on top (Which is out of bounds).

If you want to hide it Use

```
   toolbar.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

this will hide the components which is not in UIToolBar's bounds. Here, the line.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! I will add that to make the toolbars seamless I had to set its' Translucent property to false.